# Is it possible to send an SMS message from an iOS app to the current caller when a call is in progress?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony

I have searched and have not been able to find a definitive answer. I know that it is not possible to get the phone number of the current caller using Objective-C, but I don't need the number.

I want to send a text message to the current caller.  Does iOS have a method to allow you to send a text message from an app to the current caller.

The scenario is this:

- End user calls another user
- They put the person they called on speaker phone and navigate to my app
- The app has a button that allows them to share information via SMS to the person they are talking to while they are talking to them without having to do anything more than click a button (the user doesn't have to type the other person's phone number manually to send the SMS).

Comment: Supposing it was possible, how would you do it if you don't have the number and thus have no way of identifying who the caller is? Who are you going to send it to if you don't have the number and the user doesn't have to type it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No.

Apple will never allow you this.

Comment: I figured this might be impossible. Can you point me to documentation stating that this is not allowed?  I need to show proof that this is not possible.

Comment: I don't remember Apple explicitly saying what they don't allow. If it's not documented then it's not allowed. You can't send an SMS from your app without user knowing but you can display a new message dialog so that user could send the message manually.

Answer (score 3):

Sukhdeep is correct.iOS will never allow you to perform Messaging without user involvement.